# Modify req.body and res. parameters in Node.Js / Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

There is a part of my script where I need to use a function, which takes `req` and `res` data as its variables.

Is there any way to populate them without actually having to submit a form, something like

```
    req.body.entry.body = 'this is a test post about things that are apples';
```

and

```
    res.locals.user.uid = node.uid;
```

and then call on

```
    entries.submit(req, res, next);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just make a normal object.

Comment: @SLaks how? i'm sorry, i'm just starting... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where the function you are calling `entries.submit` from is, and there is probably a cleaner way to structure what you are asking. But your rough answer would be

```
someOtherFunction = function(req, res, next) {
  myReq = {
    body: {
      entry: {
        body: "this is a test post about things that are apples"
      }
    } 
  };

  myRes = {
    locals: {
      user: {
         uid: node.uid
      }
    }
  };

  entries.submit(myReq, myRes, next);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I agree there could be a cleaner way, probably I should put some of the logic inside entries.submit into a separate function, but the thing is that that logic needs req and res parameters anyway...